# Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set using spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to configure hibernate in my spring-boot project.

I have application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:url?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=name
spring.datasource.password=password

hibernate.connection.driver_class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:mysql:url
hibernate.connection.username = name
hibernate.connection.password = password
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

And method for registering user in UserDAO class:

```
public void registerUser(User u){
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(u);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    System.out.println("yay all done");
}
```

However i am recieving error:

```
> Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to
> create requested service
> [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]   at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
> com.groups.data.UserDAO.<init>(UserDAO.java:18) ~[classes/:na]    ... 52
> common frames omitted Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException:
> Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when
> 'hibernate.dialect' not set   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     ... 66 common frames
> omitted
```

I have configured dialect as it requires, i have even tried creating good old `hibernate.cfg.xml` file but the error remained the same ( it even seemed it ignored the file).

Why is ist happening? Literally yesterday it worked without problem. Today i tried creating the cfg file and it stopped working ( deleted it already ).

The more i try to configure hibernate the more it seems it was made to anger anyone who is using it and impossible to make it work.

WHat could be the problem here?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 29):

Have you added this line to your `application.properties` file ?

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

---

> **DB2**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect`
>
> **DB2 AS/400**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect`
>
> **DB2 OS390**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect`
>
> **PostgreSQL**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`
>
> **MySQL**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`
>
> **MySQL with InnoDB**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect`
>
> **MySQL with MyISAM**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect`
>
> **Oracle (any version)**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect`
>
> **Oracle 9i/10g**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect`
>
> **Sybase**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect`
>
> **Sybase Anywhere**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseAnywhereDialect`
>
> **Microsoft SQL Server**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect`
>
> **SAP DB**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.SAPDBDialect`
>
> **Informix**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect`
>
> **HypersonicSQL**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect`
>
> **Ingres**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.IngresDialect`
>
> **Progress**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.ProgressDialect`
>
> **Mckoi SQL**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.MckoiDialect`
>
> **Interbase**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.InterbaseDialect`
>
> **Pointbase**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.PointbaseDialect`
>
> **FrontBase**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.FrontbaseDialect`
>
> **Firebird**
>   `org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect`

Comment: Great answer, listing all dialects. Thanks!

Comment: @Eddy, thanks for listing all dialects; however, how would you set 2 different dialects in application.properties if your app had to talk to 2 different vendor databases?  For example DB2 and Oracle?