# Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx

I was wanted to add the data into my database, but this error cant be resolved, I follow the instruction to get newer version about my application like MySql 5.5 , mysql-connector8.0.20. but it doesnt give anything to resolve my prob, so what should I do for this error(im using Intellij IDEA 2020)

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.tubes.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:16)
    at com.tubes.dao.BarangDaoImpl.addData(BarangDaoImpl.java:17)
    at com.tubes.controller.AdminController.SaveAction(AdminController.java:94)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at com.tubes.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:14)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

FULL ERROR LOG :

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=62603:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\Kampus\OOPL\pbo220192-final-project-team-dr\out\production\untitled3;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\hibernate\hibernate\2.1.8\hibernate-2.1.8.jar;D:\Kampus\OOPL\pbo220192-final-project-team-dr\lib\dom4j-2.1.1.jar;D:\Kampus\OOPL\pbo220192-final-project-team-dr\lib\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar;D:\Kampus\OOPL\pbo220192-final-project-team-dr\lib\antlr-2.7.7.jar;D:\Kampus\OOPL\pbo220192-final-project-team-dr\lib\byte-buddy-1.10.7.jar;D:\Kampus\OOPL\pbo220192-final-project-team-dr\lib\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar;D:\Kampus\OOPL\pbo220192-final-project-team-dr\lib\classmate-1.5.1.jar;D:\Kampus\OOPL\pbo220192-final-project-team-dr\lib\FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar;D:\Kampus\OOPL\pbo220192-final-project-team-dr\lib\hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar;D:\Kampus\OOPL\pbo220192-final-project-team-dr\lib\jandex-2.1.1.Final.jar;D:\Kampus\OOPL\pbo220192-final-project-team-dr\lib\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;D:\Kampus\OOPL\pbo220192-final-project-team-dr\lib\javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar;D:\Kampus\OOPL\pbo220192-final-project-team-dr\lib\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;D:\Kampus\OOPL\pbo220192-final-project-team-dr\lib\jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar;D:\Kampus\OOPL\pbo220192-final-project-team-dr\lib\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;D:\Kampus\OOPL\pbo220192-final-project-team-dr\lib\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;D:\Kampus\OOPL\pbo220192-final-project-team-dr\lib\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar;D:\Kampus\OOPL\pbo220192-final-project-team-dr\lib\txw2-2.3.1.jar;D:\Kampus\OOPL\pbo220192-final-project-team-dr\lib\stax-ex-1.8.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.48\mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar" com.tubes.Main
    Admin
    admin
    Jun 01, 2020 5:42:34 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
    WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.251
    Jun 01, 2020 5:42:38 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.11.Final}
    Jun 01, 2020 5:42:38 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
    Jun 01, 2020 5:42:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
    WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
    Jun 01, 2020 5:42:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tubesoopl]
    Jun 01, 2020 5:42:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {}
    Jun 01, 2020 5:42:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
    Jun 01, 2020 5:42:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
    INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
    Jun 01, 2020 5:42:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
    WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : null
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
        ... 48 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.tubes.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:16)
        at com.tubes.dao.BarangDaoImpl.addData(BarangDaoImpl.java:17)
        at com.tubes.controller.AdminController.SaveAction(AdminController.java:94)
        ... 58 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:116)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:331)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:250)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:228)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:369)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
        at com.tubes.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:14)
        ... 60 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
        ... 97 more

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

this is my HibernateUtil :

```java
    public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory ourSessionFactory;
    static {
        try {

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            ourSessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        }catch (Throwable ex){
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSession() throws HibernateException {

        return ourSessionFactory;
    }
```

This is my addData

```java
    public class BarangDaoImpl implements DaoService<Barang> {
    @Override
    public int addData(Barang object) {
        int result = 0;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            session.save(object);
            transaction.commit();
            result = 1;
        }
        catch (HibernateException ex){
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        session.close();
        return result;
    }
```

This is my saveAction

```java
    private void SaveAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Alert alert = new Alert ((Alert.AlertType.ERROR));
        alert.setHeaderText (null);
        alert.setTitle ("Error");

        if(emptyForm ()){
            alert.setContentText ("Fill all of this!!");
            alert.showAndWait ();
            return;
        }

        Barang item = new Barang();
        item.setKodebarang (Integer.parseInt (txtKode.getText ().trim ()));
        item.setNamabarang (txtNama.getText());
        item.setHargabarang (Integer.parseInt (txtHarga.getText()));
        int result = getBarangDao().addData(item);
        if(result == 1){
            barangs.add(item);
            resetForm();
            alert.setTitle("Success");
            alert.setAlertType(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setContentText("Item added");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }
```

please anyone help me

Comment: strip it down to a [mcve] .. best try to separate out the hibernate/db stuff and solve that before adding any ui

Comment: you are still mixing backend and ui code - try withou any ui, just hard-code the access to hibernate and make it work. Only after it's working add the ui into the mix. Unrelated: java naming conventions, please. And beware with gender assumptions (I'm not male) .. if uncertain, avoid them :)

Comment: There are several questions addressing this error: do any of these help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282432 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548505 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51847358

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow reinaldi , try to minimize the source of error or problem

Comment: Please share configuration file or property file.